# Degree One Map induces Surjections on Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Is the following statement true:

If $f:M\to N$ is a degree one map of compact closed manifolds, then $f$ induces surjections $f^*:H_q(M)\to H_q(N)$.

I found this claimed on http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Degree_one_map . The $H_1$ case is clear to me, but I don't see how to generalize this.

Comment: The dual statement that $f$ induces injections on cohomology follows from Poincaré duality. That gets you this statement modulo torsion, I guess? Perhaps you can try to prove this on the chain level, e.g. by taking preimages of simplices in $N$?

Comment: This is exactly Theorem 67.2. on page 398 of Elements Of Algebraic Topology by James R. Munkres (non-zero degree map induces injection of all cohomology groups, degree $\pm 1$ map induces surjection on all homology groups). See this: https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Elements_Of_Algebraic_Topology/-mdQDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The+second+version+of+Poincare+duality,+in+which+the+isomorphism+is+obtained+by+use+of+cap+products,+has+consequences+that+go+far+beyond+the+naturality+diagram+just+proved.&pg=PA398&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 11):

By Poincare duality every class $x \in H_p(M;R)$ is of the form $[M] \frown \psi$, for $\psi \in H^{n-p}(M; R)$.

Now if $y \in H_p(N; R)$, then we know $y = \psi_y \frown [N]$.

Now generally for a homology class $x \in H_*(M;R)$ and $\psi \in H^*(N;R)$ we have that $f_*(x) \frown \psi = f_*(x \frown f^*\psi)$. Applying this to $x = [M]$ and $\psi = \psi_y$ we find that

$$y = [N] \frown \psi_y = f_*([M] \frown f^* \psi_y),$$ and in particular $y$ is in the image of $[M] \frown f^* \psi_y$.

Therefore, the induced map on homology of a degree-1 map is necessarily surjective.

Comment: Welcome into the Math.SE. Please, can you explain the mean of $\frown$?

Comment: @Sebastiano $\frown$ means cap product.

Comment: @Kevin.S Excuse me. Please, what is the cap product? :-(

Comment: There is a typo: "Injective" should be "surjective".